# How to make an element tag of an Angular component known or accessible to another component?

Tags: angular

How to declare or make a component's tag accessible in [this code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-enaowx)?

```
import { Component, Input, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  template: `
    <welcome name="{{ name }}"></welcome>
    <p>
      Learn from this sample application of Angular concepts.
    </p>
    <!--<list>-->
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HomePageComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add ***HomePageComponent*** in ***declarations***.

***Welcome component*** is added in declarations of more than one module.

***We can declare a component in at most one module***. We cannot declare same component in multiple modules.

Remove declarations in route module, you need not add any declarations inside route module.

I did some clean up in your code. Here is updated stackblitz -
[Stackblitz updated](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u8wadw)

Comment: Ok. So I needed to add the HomePageComponent, and the WelcomeComponent to the app.module.  Thanks!  The error seems misleading as it points to the WelcomeComponent and not the HomePageComponent.  Is there an article that explains how to manage the declaration and scope of Module and Components?

Comment: Im not sure may be https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules will help